# Two images per category at wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to add multiple images for a category in wordpress?

I've seen [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcustom-category-image/) that allows you to add a single image per category.

I would actually like to add 2 images per category. One for its header, and another one for its menu thumbnail.

Any recommendation?

Comment: You may want to use [some custom fields plugin for categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-categories/)

Comment: @vard There's no image field there. I want to be easy to maintain. Otherwise I could always use the slug as a CSS selector to set the background. But that's far from ideal.

Comment: ACF is supporting images, you can use the [gallery field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/gallery/) for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done.
One way is a bit long, and it involves

1. assigning categories and taxonomies to attachments;
2. querying media files by taxonomy so you can output them in a custom
   loop;
3. using special taxonomy queries for images to display them on archive pages;
4. adding an image to a category or taxonomy term as the category image.

.. it would require a very long answer.

But - there is a hack that would help you do it, although not as dynamic as the above one. ( although - read below it can be made dynamic as well )

what you do is basically put images with the category name like `bananas.jpg`, `pears.jpg`, `apples.jpg`, and then

```
<img src="whatever/directory/<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>.jpg" />
```

of course, in your case you would do bananas-head.jpg, pears-head.jpg, apples-head.jpg , and then `bananas-footer.jpg`, `pears-footer.jpg`, `apples-footer.jpg` etc etc.. you get the picture ( no pun intended ).

Of course, like said before, it is not so dynamic, but it can easily be converted to one by using special theme settings, where one upload an image for each category, and the theme just grabs the category image by taxonomy ID ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload multiple images using https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-multiple-images/ plugin. Please check and let me know.

Thanks!